# Generalizing compound probability distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function

From Wikipedia:

> A compound probability distribution is the probability distribution
>   that results from assuming that a random variable $X$ is distributed
>   according to some parametrized distribution $F$ with an unknown
>   parameter $\theta$  that is again distributed according to some other
>   distribution $G$. The resulting distribution $H$ is said to be the
>   distribution that results from compounding $F$ with $G$. [...] Its
>   probability density function is given by:
>
> $p_{H}(x)=\int p_{F}(x|\theta) p_{G}(\theta) d\theta$

Sometimes, it is possible to define $H$ even when $G$ is not a distribution, by using

$p'_{H}(x) = \int p_{F}(x|\theta) f_{G}(\theta) d\theta$,

$p_{H}(x) = \dfrac {p'_{H}(x)} {\int p'_{H}(x) dx}$,

where $f_{G}$ is a function such that $p_{H}$ is a well defined density function.

Does this generalization of the compound probability distribution have a name? What about '$G$'? Even though it's not a probability distribution, it kind of serves the role of a prior.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2677365/537420, where I similarly assume a uniform "prior" over real-valued parameters, and even though that prior is not a distribution, get a well defined distribution when the sample size is bigger than two.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out about [improper priors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_probability#Improper_priors). I believe $G$ would be called an improper prior.