# Posterior compounded multivariate Gaussian

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Given a sample $S = \{x_1,...,x_m\}$ from a multivariate Gaussian in ${n}$ dimensions, and the improper uniform prior over all possible such Gaussians, what is the posterior compound distribution?

In other words: Start with the improper uniform prior over all multivariate Gaussians in ${n}$ dimensions. Condition that prior on ${S}$, and find the corresponding posterior distribution ${P}$. Find the compound Gaussian distribution with mean and variance distributed according to ${P}$.

By *improper prior over all possible Gaussians*, I mean the prior that attributes the same likelihood to all means, and to all covariances.

Note that the final compound distribution will only be a proper distribution when ${m}$ is large enough (when ${n = 1}$, I believe ${m}$ needs to be at least 3).

(Partial answers will also be considered.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is a [multivariate Student distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_t-distribution) of dimension $n$:

\begin{align*}
\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{m+n}{2}-1\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{m}{2}-1\right)}\frac{1}{\pi ^{n/2} (m+1)^{n/2}|\boldsymbol{\Sigma} |^{\frac{1}{2}}}\left(1+\frac{1}{(m+1)}(\mathbf{x}-\boldsymbol{\mu} )^T\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}(\mathbf{x}-\boldsymbol{\mu} )\right)^{-\left(\frac{m+n}{2}-1\right)}
\end{align*}
where $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ and $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$ are the sample mean vector and the sample covaraince matrix, respectively:
\begin{align*}
    \boldsymbol{\mu} = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{k=1}^m \mathbf{x}_k, \quad 
    \boldsymbol{\Sigma} = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{k=1}^m \mathbf{x}_k \mathbf{x}^{T}_k -\boldsymbol{\mu} \boldsymbol{\mu}^T.
\end{align*}

As in the [univariate case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2676965/what-is-the-distribution-that-represents-our-knowledge-of-a-normal-distribution) , we need $m>2$ for the distribution to be proper. Furthermore, to avoid degeneracy, the sample size must be larger than the dimension count: $m>n$.